# Monogame: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, monodevelop, разработка-игр, monogame

Всем доброго времени суток, я изучаю monogame и у меня появилась такая проблема: когда я запускаю проект у меня вылетает такая ошибка

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Что вообще значит? И как её исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что Николас уже нашел ответ.
Ваш объект, вызывающий исключение, равен null, т.е. не был создан. При этом вы пытаетесь взаимодействовать с ним.
Для примера:

```
List<string> foo;
foo.Clear();
```

Чтобы взаимодействовать с объектом, его надо создать:

```
foo = new List<string>();
```